# Profile or debug APK : Generating signed Bundle requires you to update the Android Gradle plugin to version 3.2.0

Tags: android, gradle, plugins, version, bundle

Inside Android Studio, i use Profile or debug APK option to generate signed Bundle, but I'm getting the follwing error:

"Generating signed Bundle requires you to update the Android Gradle plugin to version 3.2.0 or higher"

[image]

If I click "Close this dialog and update the plugin" it goes to another prompt asking whether to update. Clicking "Update" appears to do nothing except close the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Update your classpath in Build.Gradle to the latest:
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"

[image]

Comment: Shogun Nassar , thank you for your help ,in Profile or debug APK we uplaod the APK file into AS. Do you know please where i can find this classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2" in the APK folder ?