# Generating signed Bundle requires: update the Android Gradle plugin to version 3.2.0 or higher

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, bundle

When I'm trying "Generate Signed Bundle / APK" I see this error: Generating signed Bundle requires you to update the Android Gradle plugin to version 3.2.0 or higher.

So I can't generate. I tried download and update Gradle. I tried fo example this solution [How to update gradle in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio) but that's not works (it's from 2013). My setting of Android Studio looks another. I've got Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1. I'm trying it with "new" app code (copy code into new project).

I tried this too: [Profile or debug APK : Generating signed Bundle requires you to update the Android Gradle plugin to version 3.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69330472/profile-or-debug-apk-generating-signed-bundle-requires-you-to-update-the-andro) .

I tried to uninstall and install back Android studio and delete Gradle.

It works only when I open older version (but this original version crashed at a mobile - I don't know why), not new version.

Where can I do update?